# use dplyr but keep groups present in a least anyway

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello let say I have a df such as :

```
Groups COL1 
G1 4
G1 32
G1 43
G2 43
G2 23
G2 0
G3 2
G3 4
G4 2
G4 1
```

and I want to keep only groups where I have at least one COL1 value >5

For that I use :

```
df %>%
  group_by(Groups) %>%
  filter(any(COL1 >5))
```

Here I should get :

```
Groups COL1 
G1 4
G1 32
G1 43
G2 43
G2 23
G2 0
```

but lets now say I want to do that but I want to keep groups in a certain list : list<-c("G4")

and if a Group is in that list I keep this group anyway (even if all value are < 5)
and I should get

```
Groups COL1 
G1 4
G1 32
G1 43
G2 43
G2 23
G2 0
G4 5
G4 5
```

where I kept 4 because it was in the list

Comment: You can simply do `df %>%
 group_by(Groups) %>%
 filter(any(COL1 > 5) | Groups %in% lst)`.

Comment: and what if I have a lot of  ```filter(any())``` lines ?? I have to add this each time ?

Comment: What does "a lot of `filter(any())` lines" mean? Do you mean you have more columns (`COL2`, `COL3`, ...) which need to be passed to `filter()` or you have more conditions just on `COL1`? It's better to adjust your example for an extended problem. If you think the answer you accepted is great enough, you can skip this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution which is close to what you want. I have re used your code and with a `left_join()` I added a new variable `Index` so that you can filter to obtain the dataframe you want. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#List
listv<-c("G4")
#Code
df %>% left_join(df %>%
  group_by(Groups) %>%
  filter(any(COL1 >5) | Groups %in% listv) %>% mutate(Index=1) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(Groups)) %>% select(-COL1)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Index)) %>% select(-Index)
```

Output:

```
  Groups COL1
1     G1    4
2     G1   32
3     G1   43
4     G2   43
5     G2   23
6     G2    0
7     G4    2
8     G4    1
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Groups = c("G1", "G1", "G1", "G2", "G2", "G2", 
"G3", "G3", "G4", "G4"), COL1 = c(4L, 32L, 43L, 43L, 23L, 0L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

Comment: oups I modified the input table, G4 only passes because it is present into the list

Comment: @chippycentra I have updated the code for you so that it fits with the list of values you use!